# how to slice pandas dataframe columns with default values instead of error

Tags: python, pandas

I have a following set of dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1234, 12345], 'col2':[123, 345], 'col3':[1000,1000] })
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1234, 12345], 'col2':[123, 345], 'col3':[1000,1000], 'col4':[1000,1000] })
```

[image]

I am trying to slice them so that I only have `['col1', 'col3', 'col4']`

[image]

While I'm able to achieve that using slicing `df[['col1','col3', 'col4']]`, in the case that `col4` doesn't exist , it gives an error. Is it possible to put a default value e.g. `nil` or `0` in case col4 doesn't exist so that I get the following when I run slicing with df1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.reindex(['col1','col3', 'col4'], axis=1)
```

Or:

```
df = df.reindex(['col1','col3', 'col4'], axis=1, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just check if it exists or not.

```
if 'col4' in df.columns:
    #do this
else:
    #then do this
```

And for example you could append 'col 4' and then set it to the 0's the dataframe in the else, if that is what you are going for!

Comment: that only works if you are uncertain about 1 column